# Form is nesting incorrectly

Tags: html, css, node.js, twitter-bootstrap, pug

I'm using Node.js, Jade and Bootstrap.
I need to render a table and on every line i need a seperate form.
I tried this:

```
    - for(var i = 0; i < renditeTabellen.length; ++i) {
      tr
        form(method="POST", action="/deleteTable")
          td#tableID #{i}
          td#tableName #{renditeTabellen[i].name}
          td#tableDate nix
          td
            button#delete.btn-danger(type="submit") Speichern
    - }
```

But i get this output:
[image]

so the `form` is not nesting in the right way. It should contain a `tr`
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HTML forms CANNOT be nested. Period.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put a form directly to `TR`. Change it to render form in a single td. As far as I can see, you do not even need to have a form wrapping all `TD`s in row. Suppose code should be like this:

```
 - for(var i = 0; i < renditeTabellen.length; ++i) {
      tr            
        td#tableID #{i}
        td#tableName #{renditeTabellen[i].name}
        td#tableDate nix
        td
          form(method="POST", action="/deleteTable")
            button#delete.btn-danger(type="submit") Speichern
    - }
```

Also, remember that only form elements (input, select, button etc.) are submitted with a form, so you need to place a value attribute on your button which should contain an ID of an item that should be deleted. Plus, button should have a name, so you can get it from post.

Comment: So you're saying a form does alwasy POST the whole page and i can access every element by name after post? If so, this would be pretry cool :D

Comment: Form never post whole page. Only form elements: all inputs, button, select, textarea and that is all. But once you have an ID passed with button, you can get everything else from database, so I see no problem here.